# Load PointerLockControl camera view to another camera

Tags: three.js

I'm using the PointerLockControls to control my camera but how would I be able to load the rotation of the current view to another camera that is not attached to anything but the scene?
I can get the yawObject position but the yawObject rotation does not show the exact view I had with the PointerLockControl camera. For example, if I output the following:
yawObject position: 183.91,10.00,-204.16 
yawObject rotation:  0.00,73.89,0.00
pitchObject position: 0.00,20.00,0.00
pitchObject rotation: -0.10,0.00,0.00

If I try to set the 2nd camera that does not have any controls with the following:
camera2.position.set(183.91,10.00,-204.16);
camera2.rotation.set(0.00,73.89,0.00);

The resulting camera2 view is not the same.

Comment: How are you managing to get `pitchObject.position` to be something other than zero?

Comment: Sorry, I had the pitch and yaw mixed up when I wrote this question. I corrected it on my original post. All I basically want to do is capture my pointerlockcontrol view and save and load it later on a camera without the controls. I can save and load it fine on the poniterlockcontrol camera.

Comment: How are you managing to get `pitchObject.position` to be something other than zero?

Comment: I increment/decrement the control yaw and pitch y position when I want to increase/decrease the camera view height. I have some views that is on upper floors and the default y position will not do. For example, I would do a controller = controls.getYawObject(); // which returns the yawObject and then execute controller.position.y = controller.position.y-1; The same is done with the pitchObject

Comment: You only need to change yaw position. Leave `pitchObject.position` at zero... Do you understand that since `camera.position` remains zero, that the world camera position is the sum of `yawObject.position` and `pitchObject.position`?

Comment: Thanks, the camera position is where it's suppose to be but the angle is not working. How do I copy the pointerlockcontrol camera angle/rotation to a camera without controls? I tried setting the yawObject rotation but it's not the correct rotation view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a second camera that has the same view direction as the camera controled by `PointerLockControls`, the key is to look at the method `PointerLockControls.getDirection()`, which returns a direction vector.

If you want to be able to set the 2nd camera's rotation directly, you do this:

```
camera2.rotation.order = 'YXZ'; // important!

. . .

camera2.rotation.set( pitchObject.rotation.x, yawObject.rotation.y, 0 );
```

where

```
yawObject = controls.getObject();

pitchObject = yawObject.children[ 0 ];
```

three.js r.67

Comment: Thank you WestLangley for your answer. This was very helpful :)