# three.js pointerlock multiplayer enemies rotation not working properly

Tags: three.js, rotation, pointerlock

I am creating a little multiplayer game basing on [this three.js pointerlock example](https://threejs.org/examples/misc_controls_pointerlock.html)

**I need to rotate the enemies avatars** on the actual player screen, so he can see the direction they are looking at, but I cannot figure out how to properly do it

At the moment each enemy is sending an object with his position and rotation to the server

```
{
    position: controls.getObject().position,            
    rotation: controls.getDirection(new THREE.Vector3())
}
```

the server receives it and sends to the actual player who with a function selects the respective enemy mesh (avatar) in the map and applies the position/rotation to it

```
var object = scene.getObjectByName(data.player);

object.position.x = data.position.x;
object.position.y = data.position.y;
object.position.z = data.position.z;

object.rotation.x = data.rotation.y;
object.rotation.y = data.rotation.x;
object.rotation.z = data.rotation.z;
```

But only the position works, **the rotation is not working properly**: the resulting rotation axes seem to be inverted and they also vary depending on the direction the actual player is looking at

---

**Edit:**

I tried also to "clone" it into another camera with different `rotation.order` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23828588/5638869)

```
var camera2 = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera2.rotation.order = 'YXZ';
var yawObject = controls.getObject();
var pitchObject = yawObject.children[0];
camera2.rotation.set(pitchObject.rotation.x, yawObject.rotation.y, 0);
```

and making enemies send

```
{
    position: controls.getObject().position,            
    rotation: camera2.rotation
}
```

but rotation is still wrong

Answer (score 0):

I realised that I can rotate objects into pointerlock direction in this way:

```
var dir = controls.getDirection(new THREE.Vector3());
var dis = 100;
mesh.lookAt({x:d.x * dis, y:d.y * dis, z:d.z * dis});
```

so I can make enemies send their **dir**ection instead of rotation, then make them look at a small **dis**tance in that direction.